Water pulsing in upstairs bathroom shower
This only happens in the upstairs bath. City water, house Cir. 1921, copper pipes, older remodeled bath/shower, turn on shower to warm up, flush toilet, pulse begins (staccato not hammer). Turn on sink water, pulse stops, turn off, pulse continues, toilet tank fills and stops water flow, pulsing stops.
I can't remember when this started; just got used to it happening. My neighbor down the street has the same problem but worse pulsing.

How long does this pulsing last? Are your water pipes expanding because of the hot water you are using when you "turn on the shower to warm up"?

indications are it is the pressure regulator
go outside and find it, then give it one turn clockwise
if that doesn't help, you might need to replace it
